# Bug en Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, .net, visual-studio-2022

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en visual studio 2022 de repente me sale este error, creo un nuevo proyecto y me sigue saliendo el mismo erro despues de un tiempo, alguien mas le ha pasad0?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás algunas de las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61140481/255257) (en inglés) puedan resultarte de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias hermano, lo solucione

Comment: Me alegra que se haya resuelto tu problema. Quisiera sugerir que agregues la respuesta a tu propia pregunta con dicha solución. Po rotro lado, que [edit] la pregunta y dejes el mensaje de error como texto (gracias a eso pude encontrar la publicación que te sugerí en SO en inglés). Recuerda que el código y los errores, aquí, siempre se debieran publicar como texto.